# Toggling list, h4 header getting changed to default <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Breakfast, starts off as a `h4` and ends up with the same styling as the `li` elements, I was just wondering how to keep it as an `h4`.
Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div class="recipe">
  <h4>Breakfast</h4>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Banana Berry Crepes - 250 Cals</li>
    <li>Strawberry Parfaits - 170 Cals</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.recipe {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
    display: none;
}

h4 {
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_alt_rgbold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
    border; solid 4px 
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".recipe").click(function () {

    $recipe = $(this);
    $content = $recipe.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        $recipe.text(function () {
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Breakfast" : "Breakfast";
        });
    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/auug5dpk/) fiddle

I have changed your JS code as below

```
$recipe.children('h4').text(function () {
        return $content.is(":visible") ? "Breakfast" : "Breakfast";
    });
```

Hope this answered your question :)